# Unable start google-chrome appilcation (ubuntu_gtk_set_use_overlay_scrollbar)

Tags: google-chrome, gtk

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 and have some problem with my google-chrome, chromium and other apps. The problem like in this screen shot:

[image]

```
sahl@hawk:~$ google-chrome
/opt/google/chrome/chrome: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/liboverlay-scrollbar.so: undefined symbol: ubuntu_gtk_set_use_overlay_scrollbar
```

I have updated and upgraded, but still stuck in this problem, how to fix it?

Comment: What happens if you do `google-chrome-stable`?

Comment: "some problem with my google-chrome, chromium and other apps" indicates that the issue is **not** limited to google-chrome/chromium-browser, IMO.

Comment: still face the same problem if  I run with google-chrome-stable

Comment: update, I was fix this problem by remove and install libgtk2.0-0 but some package of my application removed (https://pastebin.com/8smhRW8S) how to fix it.,,?